# How to handle dependecies between branches in git-flow?

Tags: git, dependencies, git-flow, branching-strategy

I've been working on feature_A while another dev works on feature_B. Now, the other dev needs a small functionallity that's implemented in my feature_A, but I've not finished the whole feature itself. How should I share the code to the other dev? Is it against git-flow branching model? Can I simply merge feature_A into feature_B?

Answer (score 2):

Simplest to implement correctly is going to be make a branch off the common base that has just the bits feature-b needs and merge from that to both existing feature tips. Since the code's already in feature-a you can just `-s ours` merge it.

```
git checkout -b minifeature-from-a $(git merge-base feature-a feature-b)
hackity hack hack
git commit
git checkout feature-a
git merge -s ours minifeature-from-a
git checkout feature-b
git merge minifeature-from-a
```

If the existing commits implementing the minifeature are isolated, if they don't also make other changes, "hackity hack hack" above is just a cherry-pick of those commits; if those existing commits also make other changes, it might or might not pay to rebase your own work to achieve that isolation, that's up to you.

Comment: And why is this correctly implemented? Why can I just merge feature_A into feature_B?

Comment: Because this only merges that one detail that feature-b wants, not the rest of what's on feature-a, which I understood you to say is incomplete and still under development. Merge that to feature-b too and you'll have to do your feature-a work on both tips. Yuck. Why do that?

Comment: I got it. And why not just cherry-pick the commit I want from feature_A?

Comment: If you can, do. I said that: "If the existing commits implementing the minifeature are isolated, if they don't also make other changes, "hackity hack hack" above is just a cherry-pick of those commits".

Comment: I mean, just first `git checkout feature_B` and then `git cherry-pick <commit-from-feature_A>`

Comment: Cherry-picking straight across works when you can do it, if you don't mind leaving the door open for unnecessary conflicts later, really at that point it's a matter of preference. I like having merges recorded. Cherry-picks are unrecorded selective merges. Other people dislike recorded merges and want everything to *look* as linear as possible, no matter what really happened.  If it turns out your minifeature implementation has a bug, the cherry-pick solution leaves you with a scavenger hunt for where the bad code has gotten to and scattershot fixes all over the graph to correct them.